# Drop down list box with dynamic month and year in Date Prompt in Cognos

Tags: cognos

I want to add the current month, and the previous two months to a prompt, for a user to select.

e.g. if this month is `2008 Nov`, `ddlbox` should show the following:

```
112008
102008
092008
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    ListItem item = new ListItem(string.Format("{0: MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-i)));
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Try this :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a query subject with SQL like this Oracle example:

```
SELECT to_char(add_months(SYSDATE, -1 * LEVEL + 1), 'MMYYYY') AS mon
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY rownum < 4
```